# How to persist an image in core data with external storage

Tags: ios, core-data, uiimage

In my app I have an image for a user profile that a user can obtain from the camera. I do not want to manage an image outside of core data since I have a user object that manages all other data in the object very nicely.

What data type do I store the image as?

Does anyone have an example of where and how to implement setAllowsExternalBinaryDataStorage?  I am not able to find an example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track.  You want to store it as NSData.  When you open the core data model gui (the one where you have a visual graph of your core data model) -- Select the attribute, then on the right - where you would give it a type and default value and such -- there will be a check box that says almost exactly what you want.

Check that box and Core Data will automatically use (and manage) the external file to store the data object.